# Problem with command for memory stress - Unexpected end of string

Tags: python, quoting

I have a problem with this command in Python.

```
stress-ng --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemAvailable/{printf "%d\n", $2 * 0.95;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep -m 1
```

I need double quotation marks at the beginning and end of the command, like:

```
"stress-ng --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemAvailable/{printf "%d\n", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep -m 1"
```

After escaping the interior quotation marks, I have unexpected end of string.

```
"stress-ng --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemAvailable/{printf \"%d\n\", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep -m 1"
```

Does anyone have an idea how to deal with this?

Comment: So, what it is exactly that you're doing? What's the error you get exactly? The string in that last code block seems a valid python string to me, and the interpreter parses it ok.

Comment: You might need to escape the pre-existing backslash;  i.e., say ``\"%d\\n\"``.

Comment: Thank you G-Man Says 'Reinstate Monica, it's work!

Comment: I just posted an explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Characters 52-59 of your string,

```
"stress-ng --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemAvailable/{printf \"%d\n\", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep -m 1"
                                                   ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

shown highlighted above and isolated below:

```
                                            \  "  %  d  \  n  \  "
```

are parsed as:

1. `"`     (a quote character (which was escaped))
2. `%`
3. `d`
4. (a newline character, hex 0x0A)
5. `"`

with the result that the shell sees two lines:

```
stress-ng --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemAvailable/{printf "%d
", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep -m 1
```

so `awk` sees the following two-line program:

```
/MemAvailable/{printf "%d
", $2 * 0.9;}
```

Awk parses its program a line at a time
(unless you use backslash+newline), so it sees unbalanced quotes. 
As you know, you want to pass

```
/MemAvailable/{printf "%d\n", $2 * 0.9;}
```

to `awk`; i.e., to let `awk` see the `\n` characters
rather than the actual newline character. 
So you need to escape the `\` in your `\n`:

```
"stress-ng --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemAvailable/{printf \"%d\\n\", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep -m 1"
                                                       ↑
```

By the way, your first command uses 0.95,
but then you change it to 0.9 in the next two lines.

Comment: Hmm.  I suspect that my explanation is not 100% right, but this is the answer.

Comment: Good catch. I think the error would come from awk and not the shell. (Which also would have been apparent had they bothered to post the actual error message.) The shell's fine with multi-line quoted strings.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, I agree. I've rewritten my explanation.